# ILGenerator логика для свойства в set

Tags: c#

как на **ILGenerator**  можно сделать:

```
public string MyMethod(string s, int i)
{
  return s + "____" + i;
}

private static string _s;
public static string ss
{
   get { return _s; }
   set {
           var x = MyMethod(value, 100);
           _s = x;
       }
}
```

**я делаю так:**

```
var setter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + name, getSetAttr, null, new[] {type});
var setIL = setter.GetILGenerator();

setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 100);
setIL.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, null);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);

setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

но не работает вызов метода **MyMethod()**....

Comment: Используйте `TypeBuilder.DefineProperty()`.

Comment: ммм я немного не доканца написал что я хочу получить что именно не работает, не получается вызвать метод MyMethod(...)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для вызова Instance-метода (метода объекта, не статического) необходимо передать первым параметром объект, у которого вызывается метод.

Логика вызова метода с 2я параметрами будет такой

пуш объекта
пуш аргумента 1
пуш аргумента 2
вызов

Каждому инстанс методу при вызове 0м параметром передается объект, у которого вызывают этот метод

в данном случае код будет таким

```
ldarg.0
ldarg.1
ldc.i4 100
call method
```

PS:
nop не нужен (наверное подсмотрел ildasmом). Nopы вставляет компилятор на тех местах где нет кода (например, скобки) для того, что б дебагер мог ставить в этих точках брейкпоинты.